# Suppose $x^a = x^b$ is integral for two integers $a,b$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. Is $x$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is the final step in my proof for a larger homework problem - if I can prove that this statement is true, then I have finished my other proof - however my mind has gone blank and I cannot solve this. Any pointers?

Suppose $x^a, x^b$ are integral for two positive integers $a,b$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = 1$. Is $x$ an integer?

Comment: Sorry, I submitted before adding some more info:

I know that $ap+bq=1$ for some p,q integers. So $x=x^{ap+bq}$.
So $x=(x^a)^p(x^b)^q$. But since ap+bq=1, one of p,q is positive and one is negative, so how do I know that $(x^a)^p(x^b)^q$ is an integer?

Comment: You can click on the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/352611/edit) button in the question above and type in whatever you want.

Comment: What sort of thing is $x$? Is it real? Complex? Integer? Rational? Something else altogether?

Comment: If $x^a = x^b$ for $a \ne b$ then $x^{a - b} = 1$ with $a - b \ne 0$, so that $x = 1$ (or perhaps $x = \pm 1$, if $a - b$ is even) is the only real solution.

Comment: @yamatehbestsf The title doesn't match the body of the question.  I doubt you really mean to say that $x^a = x^b$, only that they are both integers.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, sorry! I will edit.

Answer (score 6):

By Bezout's Theorem, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as+bt=1$. It follows that $x^1=(x^a)^s(x^b)^t$. Thus $x$ is rational.

But if $x$ is rational and not an integer, and $n$ is a positive integer, then $x^n$ cannot be an integer. This follows from the **Rational Roots Theorem**. For if $c$ is an integer, the only rational solutions of $x^n-c=0$ are of the form $k/l$, where $k$ divides $c$ and $l$ divides $1$. In particular, we must have $l=\pm 1$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I understand it perfectly now.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the proof of the Rational Roots Theorem is a variant of the usual proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(a,b)=1\implies \exists\,n,m\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;na+mb=1\implies$$

$$x=x^{na+mb}=(x^a)^n\cdot(x^b)^m=(x^a)^n\cdot(x^a)^m=x^{a(n+m)}\ldots$$

Comment: Oops, thanx @CameronBuie

Comment: It might be useful to the OP knowing that $(a,b)$ is a common notation for $\text{gcd}(a,b)$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff  Thanks! I didn't see that.

Comment: Don't mention it, @AméricoTavares. You can erase now your comments, if you like. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio done, thanks!